# Moment get current date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get current date using the Moment library? Not timestamp, but date. So please don't refer to that timestamp question already to be found.

I know how to get it in regular javascript, but I need a moment object with current date.

What about timezone, how to get current date in certain timezone?

Comment: [http://momentjs.com/timezone/](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Doesn't that refer to another library? One cannot do it with regular moment library?

Comment: I did read documentations before asking this. But couldn't find it with a quick look.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Just call moment as a function without any arguments:

```
moment()
```

For timezone information with moment, look at the `moment-timezone` package: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: How to get date in certain timezone?

Comment: Didn't find duplicate for this. I could be wrong that it exists. Could you provide one? And please, one for momemt.js!

Comment: ```moment().valueOf()```

Comment: moment().toDate() will return actual Date object.

Comment: moment().toString()

Comment: Actually it is not correct answer, because you call for moment js without arguments, it create object as "datetime", and not "date". In this case comparison `moment('[current date, 12/04/2019]').isSameOrAfter(moment())` will return incorrect result